# Windows 10 toggle settings using only keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

(Windows 10 Home 64-bit Version 1703)

In Windows 10 Settings app you can use the TAB and arrow keys to navigate between settings. How do you toggle ON/OFF settings without using the mouse or trackpad? (I.e keyboard shortcut)

[image]

Comment: There isn't a keyboard shortcut

Comment: What about using the space bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spacebar will select things and flip switches. Use the arrow keys to move sliders or scroll through lists.

Bonus Tip: Use Shift+Tab to go back through the items.